# cups or cups-client when using a network postscript printer?

Tags: raspbian, printing, cups

I am using raspbian, and there is no printer configuration in the Preferences section of the OS.

All I want is to print to a postscript printer that is on my network.

When reading up on it, some suggest to install cups-client, some suggest cups.

I tried the former... However, after installing there is no /etc/cups so the next step in the instructions: editing /etc/cups/client.conf cannot be followed.
Surely, I don't want to manually create /etc/cups as I don't even know what directory permissions to use.

Answer (score 1):

Install this stuff

`sudo apt install cups cups-ipp-utils system-config-printer printer-driver-cups-pdf`

system-config-printer is the piece you're looking for that's missing from the September build of plain Raspbian.